# Accessing and adding to a number in nasm

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I am having trouble with this code. I have trying to add 16 to the number 656 while keeping the same structure of my code. I marked the parts I would like you to ignore. I am new to this website, if I should explain anything better please let me know. Thank you all for your time. This is the code that has been written. I think I am just lost in all the registers.

The goal is to have 656 stored in rbx and add 16 to 656 and replace that value in rbx.

```
        default rel
        section .text
        extern peek_byte
        extern read_byte
        extern write_byte
        extern raise_error
entry:
        mov rbx, rdi
        mov rax, 656
        mov [rbx + 0], rax
        mov rax, rbx
        or rax, 1
        add rbx, 8
        push rax
        mov rax, [rsp + 0] I would like to keep up to this the same.

        mov r9, rax
        and r9, 7
        cmp r9, 1
        jne raise_error
        xor rax, 1
        add rax, 16
        mov [rbx + 0], rax
        mov rax, rbx
        or rax, 1
        add rbx, 8
        mov rax, 120
        push rax
        
       mov rax, [rsp + 8] I do not wish to edit this part or beyond
        mov r9, rax
        and r9, 7
        cmp r9, 1
        jne raise_error
        xor rax, 1
        mov rax, [rax + 0]
        add rsp, 8
        add rsp, 8
        ret
```

Comment: It's unclear what you want, but since you changed `rbx` it's no longer pointing to the same place. Also `rax` is destroyed so you no longer have the `656` accessible.

Comment: @Jester Thank you for your time replying. The idea is rbx is my heap and I am trying to get the value that is stored there and replace it with 656+16. I am sorry I was not clear. I will add it to my question.

Comment: Since you do `add rbx, 8` if you want to add 16 to the 656 already in memory, you need `add qword [rbx-8], 16`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to @jester. His reply helped me. I am going to show what parts got fixed in order to achieve the desired result

```
        mov r9, rax
        and r9, 7
        cmp r9, 1
        jne raise_error
        xor rax, 1
        mov rax, [rax + 0]
        mov r9, rax
        and r9, 15
        cmp r9, 0
        jne raise_error
        Add rax, 16
        mov [rbx + -8], rax <--
        mov rax, 120
        push rax``
```

Comment: `xor rax, 1` / `mov rax, [rax + 0]` - really, you flip the low bit of the address before the 8-byte load?  So the two possible locations overlap by 7 bytes.  That seems extremely weird.  Did you maybe want `movzx eax, byte [rax]`?  Also, once you have the load result, you could just `test al, 15` / `jnz raise_error` to check that the low 4 bits of RAX are all zero.  (JNE and JNZ are the same instruction, different semantic meaning for humans.)